# Mortarboard badge?

Tags: support, badges

I'm curious - there is the "[mortarboard](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard)" badge for "Earned at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day".

Yesterday I did earn 200+ reputation, but did not receive the badge. Noticed that few people actually have. Is there something wrong or is there something I've misunderstood?

Comment: The association bonus does not count.

Comment: Oh, I see. That was not clear.

Comment: See: [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) and [Mortarboard badge not awarded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178811/mortarboard-badge-not-awarded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the explanation given in meta.SO posts
[Mortarboard badge not awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178811/mortarboard-badge-not-awarded) and
[Mortarboard badges being awarded as a result of bounties after recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88465/mortarboard-badges-being-awarded-as-a-result-of-bounties-after-recalc/) it seems that reputation from association bonus is not counted towards Mortarboard badge. (But the reputation from bounties is.)

(This was already mentioned in comments, but I am reposting this as an answer, so that this question does not remain unanswered.)